# Is there any way to delete app engine's useless datastore indexes

Tags: google-app-engine

I made a lots of  indexes for testing,is it gonna call any issue?then how to delete them?
I aready delete them from my datastore-indexes.xml.

Comment: What are you talking about? Which technologies, platforms etc?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use appcfg.py from the App Engine python SDK (yes, even if you're using Java; there's an open [issue](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1893) to correct this oversight) to remove indexes, with the vacuum_indexes option.